# Specify html template from jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to put some `datepicker`s in multiple `html` templates.

What I currently have right now only works in my index.html, but if I try to do the same in another template, it does not work. I kind of understand why, but I don't know how to fix it.

datepicker.js

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/datepicker/datepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- THIS WORKS -->
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Another.html

```
<div>
  <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK -->
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<div>
```

Comment: You cannot have `<input />` inside `<p>` and change it to `class="datepicker"`. And er... `Another.html` should also have all the stuff under `<head>` tag.

Comment: since you are calling template so multiple inputs with same id has been introduced, kindly edit the `id` of your another file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add **class** attribute instead of **id** ti your inputs

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});


<body>
  <!-- THIS WORKS -->
  <p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
</body>

 <p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your js file is not loading properly please make sure that all js files properly included in each html template and also use unique id for datepicker